# NextJS and Storybook not rendering images and global styles

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, next.js, storybook

what is the best way to load global styles and images for Storybook in NextJS?

Below are the following Storybook files (config.js and scs-loader.scss and webpack.config.js)

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
            presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
        },
    });

    config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(svg|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: require.resolve('file-loader')
    });
    return config;
};
```

**config.js**

```
import '!file-loader!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./scss-loader.scss';
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';
configure(require.context('../components', true, /\.stories\.(j|t)sx?$/), module);
```

**scss.loader.scss**

```
@import '../styles/global.scss';
```

Using the above config I can get a successful Storybook build however I do not see any global styles nor do I see any images referenced in global.scss

If i remove the file-loader in config.js as follows

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./scss-loader.scss';
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';
configure(require.context('../components', true, /\.stories\.(j|t)sx?$/), module);
```

I see this error.

```
Error: Can't resolve '/images/hero.jpg' in 'D:\dev\personal\nextjs-ts\.storybook'
```

If I then go and remove all the images from global.scss I can then load Storybook and I can see the global styles however I've lost all the images. I need to try and get images and global styles working in tandem. Thanks.

Here is an example of how the images are referenced in global.scss.

```
.hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: url('/images/hero.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```